# Inform the compiler that a variable might be updated from another thread

Tags: c#, .net

This would generally be done using `volatile`. But in the case of a `long` or `double` that's impossible.

Perhaps just making it `public` is enough, and the compiler then knows that this can be used by another assembly and won't "optimize it out"? Can this be relied upon? Some other way?

To be clear, I'm not worried about concurrent reading/writing of the variable. Only one thing - that it doesn't get optimized out. (Like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/1284007/939213 .)

Comment: Use the Random class, it will have more predictable behavior.  Or System.Threading.Volatile

Comment: can you show some code that you think might be optimized away?

Comment: How are you planing on updating this variable "from another thread"? This isnt really how managed code works.

Comment: @HansPassant Can you give an example of what you mean? I don't understand.

Comment: @Batavia It's linked to in the question. Did you follow the link?

Comment: @OwlSolo From time to time one thread Invokes a method on another with a `double` parameter. But that `double` might be optimized-out in that method (by the compiler).

Comment: Well the problem is, double and long operation are not atomic on 32bit system, so afaik you shouldnt do this at all. Use volatile int instead. However if you absolutely want to GC.KeepAlive should do the trick

Comment: Why can't volatile be used? [what about this?](http://igoro.com/archive/volatile-keyword-in-c-memory-model-explained/)

Comment: @m_a_s Double and long types are 64bit wide, on 32 bit system they require more than one operation to be computated (aka not atomic), this means that thread interoperability between them is a lot more difficult as you would need proper lock management to ensure that no invalid inbetween values are being used. Therefore these two cannot carry the volatile keyword in c# in the first place

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks. I didn't know about those new `Volatile` methods.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to prevent code removal is to use the code.

if you are worries about optimizing the while loop in your example

```
class Test  
{
   long foo;

   static void Main()
   {
      var test = new Test();

      new Thread(delegate() { Thread.Sleep(500); test.foo = 255; }).Start();

      while (test.foo != 255) ;
      Console.WriteLine("OK");
   }
}
```

you still could use volatile to do this by modifying your while loop

```
volatile int temp;

//code skipped in this sample
while(test.foo != 255) { temp = (int)foo;}
```

Now assuming you are SURE you won't have any thread safety issues. you are using your long foo so it won't be optimized away. and you don't care about losing any part of your long since you are just trying to keep it alive.

Make sure you mark your code very clearly if you do something like this. possibly write a VolatileLong class that wraps your long (and your volatile int) so other people understand what you are doing

also other thread-safty tools like locks will prevent code removal. for example the compiler is smart enough not to remove the double if in the sinleton pattern like this.

```
if (_instance == null) {
  lock(_lock) {
       if (_instance == null) { 
          _instance = new Singleton();
        }
   }
}
return _instance;
```